# Using Plotly in shinydashboard, buttons too large to see plot

Tags: r, plotly, shinydashboard

I'm using Plotly's tutorial for shiny in my shinydashboard app (https://plot.ly/r/shiny-tutorial/).

For some reason, whenever I run the app and go to the Plotly tab, if I try to interact with the plot the buttons usually located on the top right of a Plotly plot become so large, they overshadow the plot.

[image: Large buttons]

Here is my ui code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(rCharts)
library(shiny)
library(xtable)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
PopData <- read.csv("CountyPopLong.csv", header=T)
ChangeData <- read.csv("CountyChangeLong.csv", header=T)
CountyPop <- read.csv("CountyPopWide.csv", header=T)
CountyChange <- read.csv("CountyChangeWide.csv", header=T)
CntyInfo <- read.csv("CntyCensusInfo.csv", header=T)
CityPop <- read.csv("CityData.csv", header=T)
CityPopLong <- read.csv("CityPop.csv", header=T)
CityChange <- read.csv("CityChangeWide.csv", header=T)
CityChangeLong <- read.csv("CityChangeLong.csv", header=T)
CityInfo <- read.csv("CityCensusInfo.csv", header=T)
TwpInfo <- read.csv("TwpCensusInfo.csv", header=T)
TwpPop <- read.csv("TownshipPopWide.csv", header=T)
TwpPopLong <- read.csv("TownshipPopLongWithCounty.csv", header=T)
TwpChange <- read.csv("TwpChangeWide.csv", header=T)
TwpChangeLong <- read.csv("TwpChangeLong.csv", header=T)
MHIdata <- read.csv("CountyMHILong.csv", header=T)
PCIdata <- read.csv("CountyPCILong.csv", header=T)
CityACS <- read.csv("CityACSLong.csv", header=T)
TwpACS <- read.csv("TwpACSLong.csv", header=T)
CountyBGLong <- read.csv("CountyBG2000to2010long.csv", header=T)
CityBGLong <- read.csv("CityBG2000to2010long.csv", header=T)
TwpBGLong <- read.csv("TwpBrainGain2000to2010long.csv", header=T)
CountyBG90Long <- read.csv("CountyBG1990to2000long.csv", header=T)
CityBG90Long <- read.csv("CityBG1990to2000long.csv", header=T)
TwpBG90Long <- read.csv("TwpBrainGain1990to2000long.csv", header=T)
options(RCHART_WIDTH=500, RCHART_HEIGHT=500)

dashboardPage(
      header <- dashboardHeader(

      title = "CST Datapage"
      ),



      dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
          sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("County Table", tabName="County-Table"),

            menuItem("Township", tabName="Township",
              menuSubItem("Table", tabName = "Table"),
              menuSubItem("Chart", tabName = "Chart")
          ),

            menuItem("Plotly Stuff", tabName = "Plotly-Stuff")
        )),

      tags$head(

        tags$style(HTML("
                        .sidebar{height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto; }
                        .dataTables_wrapper { overflow-x: scroll; }
                        .rChart {height: 500px, width: 100%}
                        "))
      )  

      ),

      dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName =  "Table",

              tabBox(

              title = "Township Table",
              id= "TwpPopTable", height = "5000px", width = "1000px",
              tabPanel("Download Data", 
              fluidPage(
                              absolutePanel(draggable=F, top=125, left = 250, width = "40.2%",
                                            sidebarPanel(
                                              helpText("The township data is organized by county. To view a specific townshipâs population, first select the county it is located. You can compare multiple townships by holding down âCTRLâ while selecting your desired counties."),
                                              selectInput("County4", 
                                                          "Select a County:", 
                                                          c("All", 
                                                            unique(as.character(TwpPop$County))),
                                                          selected = "All",
                                                          multiple = TRUE
                                                          #                                                                               , selectize = FALSE
                                              ),
                                              helpText("To download the full dataset in .csv format, click the button below. Customized data can also be copied and pasted into an Excel spreadsheet with the formatting intact."),
                                              downloadButton('twpPopDownload', label = "Download Data"),
                                              width = 12)))),
              tabPanel("Table", 
                              mainPanel(dataTableOutput(outputId="TwpPopTable"),
                                        p("Source: U.S. Census Bureau, Decennial Censuses 1900-2010"))


               ))),


      tabItem((tabName = "Chart"),

                fluidRow(  
                  column(width=5,
                      box(   
                      showOutput("TwpPopChart", "nvd3"), status= "primary",
                      p("Source: U.S. Census Bureau, Decennial Censuses 1900-2010")
                      , widths = c(1, 10))), 

                  absolutePanel(draggable=T, top=200, left = 1000, width = "20%",
                                helpText("The township data is organized by county. To view a specific townshipâs population, first select the county it is located. You can compare multiple townships by holding down âCTRLâ while selecting your desired counties. Then select the communities you want to compare by clicking on the legend."),
                                selectInput("County5", 
                                            "Select a County:", 
                                            c(unique(as.character(TwpPopLong$County))),
                                            selected = "Aitkin",
                                            multiple = TRUE
                                            #                                                                               , selectize = FALSE
                                )))

      ),

      tabItem(
        (tabName = "County-Table"),

              h2("Ayyyyyy")

              ),



      tabItem(
        (tabName = "Plotly-Stuff"),

          fluidRow( 
          mainPanel(plotlyOutput("trendPlot", width="100%")),


          sliderInput("bins", "Numbner of bins:", min=1,max=50,value=10))
      )),

      #Below is for colors display of the 

      tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                .skin-blue .main-header .logo{
                  font-family: Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
                  font-weight: bold;
                  font-size: 24px;
                  color: #FFFF1C;
                }

                .skin-blue .main-header .logo{
                  background-color: #FF9900;
                }

                .skin-blue .main-header .navbar{
                  background-color: #FF9900;
                }

                .skin-blue .main-sidebar{
                  background-color: #FF9900;
                }

                .skin-blue .main-sidebar{
                  font-family: Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
                  font-weight: bold;
                  font-size: 12px;
                  color:#FFFF1C;
                }

                .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu .active a{
                  color: #FFFF1C;
                }

                .skin-blue .main-header .logo:hover{
                  background-color: #FF9900;
                }

                ')


      ))

))
```

Here is my server code:

```
library(ggplot2)
  library(plyr)
  library(rCharts)
  library(shiny)
  library(xtable)
  library(RColorBrewer)
  library(shinythemes)
  library(shinydashboard)
  library(dplyr)
  library(plotly)
  PopData <- read.csv("CountyPopLong.csv", header=T)
  ChangeData <- read.csv("CountyChangeLong.csv", header=T)
  CountyPop <- read.csv("CountyPopWide.csv", header=T)
  CountyChange <- read.csv("CountyChangeWide.csv", header=T)
  CntyInfo <- read.csv("CntyCensusInfo.csv", header=T)
  CityPop <- read.csv("CityData.csv", header=T)
  CityPopLong <- read.csv("CityPop.csv", header=T)
  CityChange <- read.csv("CityChangeWide.csv", header=T)
  CityChangeLong <- read.csv("CityChangeLong.csv", header=T)
  CityInfo <- read.csv("CityCensusInfo.csv", header=T)
  TwpInfo <- read.csv("TwpCensusInfo.csv", header=T)
  TwpPop <- read.csv("TownshipPopWide.csv", header=T)
  TwpPopLong <- read.csv("TownshipPopLongWithCounty.csv", header=T)
  TwpChange <- read.csv("TwpChangeWide.csv", header=T)
  TwpChangeLong <- read.csv("TwpChangeLong.csv", header=T)
  MHIdata <- read.csv("CountyMHILong.csv", header=T)
  PCIdata <- read.csv("CountyPCILong.csv", header=T)
  CityACS <- read.csv("CityACSLong.csv", header=T)
  TwpACS <- read.csv("TwpACSLong.csv", header=T)
  CountyBGLong <- read.csv("CountyBG2000to2010long.csv", header=T)
  CityBGLong <- read.csv("CityBG2000to2010long.csv", header=T)
  TwpBGLong <- read.csv("TwpBrainGain2000to2010long.csv", header=T)
  CountyBG90Long <- read.csv("CountyBG1990to2000long.csv", header=T)
  CityBG90Long <- read.csv("CityBG1990to2000long.csv", header=T)
  TwpBG90Long <- read.csv("TwpBrainGain1990to2000long.csv", header=T)
  options(RCHART_WIDTH=800, RCHART_HEIGHT=600)


  function(input, output) {

    output$table <- renderDataTable(iris)

    set.seed(122)
    histdata <- rnorm(500)

    ######################## POPULATION OUTPUTS ########################
    output$PopTable <- renderDataTable({
      data <- CountyPop
      if (input$County != "All"){
        data <- data[data$County %in% input$County,]
      }
      data
    }, options =list(aoColumnDefs = list(list(sClass="alignCenter",aTargets=c(list("_all")) )),  pageLength=10))

    output$PopChart <- renderChart({
      names(PopData) = gsub("\\.", "", names(PopData))
      n1 <- nPlot(Population ~ Year, data = PopData, group = "County", type = 'lineChart')
      n1$addParams(dom = 'PopChart')
      n1$yAxis(axisLabel = "Population", width = 62)      
      n1$xAxis(axisLabel = "Year")
      n1$chart(forceY = c(0, 1))
      n1$xAxis(tickValues=c(1900, 1910, 1920, 1930, 1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010))
      return(n1)
    })

    output$countyPopDownload <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() { paste('MNCountyPopData', '.csv', sep='') },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(PopData, file)
      }) 

    output$CityPopTable <- renderDataTable({
      data <- CityPop
      if (input$County2 != "All"){
        data <- data[data$County %in% input$County2,]
      }
      data
    }, options =list(aoColumnDefs = list(list(sClass="alignCenter",aTargets=c(list("_all")) )),  pageLength=10))

    output$CityPopChart <- renderChart({
      var <- reactive({input$County3})
      DF <- subset(CityPopLong, County %in% var())
      names(DF) = gsub("\\.", "", names(DF))
      n2 <- nPlot(Population ~ Year, data = DF, group = "Name", type = 'lineChart')
      n2$addParams(dom = 'CityPopChart')
      n2$yAxis(axisLabel = "Population", width = 62)      
      n2$xAxis(axisLabel = "Year")
      n2$xAxis(tickValues=c(1900, 1910, 1920, 1930, 1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010))
      n2$chart(forceY = c(0, 1))
      return(n2)
    })

    output$cityPopDownload <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() { paste('MNCityPopData', '.csv', sep='') },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(CityPop, file)
      }) 

    output$TwpPopTable <- renderDataTable({
      data <- TwpPop
      if (input$County4 != "All"){
        data <- data[data$County %in% input$County4,]
      }
      data
    }, options =list(aoColumnDefs = list(list( sClass="alignCenter",aTargets=c(list("_all"))  )),  pageLength=10))


    renderChart_pct <- function(expr, env = parent.frame(), quoted = FALSE) {
      func <- shiny::exprToFunction(expr, env, quoted)
      function() {
        rChart_ <- func()
        cht_style <- sprintf("<style>.rChart {width: %s; height: %s} </style>",
                             #### change these here to desired %
                             "100%", "100%")
        cht <- paste(capture.output(rChart_$print()), collapse = '\n')
        HTML(paste(c(cht_style, cht), collapse = '\n'))
      }
    }

    output$TwpPopChart <- renderChart({
      var <- reactive({input$County5})
      DF <- subset(TwpPopLong, County %in% var())
      names(DF) = sub("\\.", "", names(DF))
      n2 <- nPlot(Population ~ Year, data = DF, group = "Name", type = 'lineChart')
      n2$addParams(dom = 'TwpPopChart')
      n2$yAxis(axisLabel = "Population", width = 62)      
      n2$xAxis(axisLabel = "Year")
      n2$xAxis(tickValues=c(1900, 1910, 1920, 1930, 1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010))
      n2$chart(forceY = c(0, 1))
      n2$chart(height=500)
      n2$set(width=500)
      return(n2)
    })

    output$twpPopDownload <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() { paste('MNTownshipPopData', '.csv', sep='') },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(TwpPop, file)
      })

    ######################## POPULATION CHANGE OUTPUTS ########################

    output$ChangeTable <- renderDataTable({
      data <- CountyChange
      if (input$County6 != "All"){
        data <- data[data$County %in% input$County6,]
      }
      data
    }, options =list(aoColumnDefs = list(list(sClass="alignCenter",aTargets=c(list("_all"))  )),  pageLength=10))  

    output$ChangeChart <- renderChart({
      names(ChangeData) = gsub("\\.", "", names(ChangeData))
      n3 <- nPlot(PercentChange ~ Year, data = ChangeData, group = "County", type = 'lineChart')
      n3$addParams(dom = 'ChangeChart')
      #     n3$yAxis(tickValues=function(d) {return(d + "%")})
      ##    ^infinite recursion
      #     n3$yAxis(tickFormat="#!function(d) {return d3.format('%Y'));}!#" )
      ##    ^all axis values gone, chart turns static
      #     n3$yAxis(labelType='percent')
      ##     ^ only for pie charts
      #     n3$yAxis(tickFormat=function(d) { return(parseInt(d, 10) + "%")})
      ##     ^ "could not find function 'd3.format'"
      n3$yAxis(axisLabel = "Percent Change from Previous Decade", width = 62)      
      n3$xAxis(axisLabel = "Year")
      n3$xAxis(tickValues=c(1900, 1910, 1920, 1930, 1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010))
      return(n3)
    })

    output$countyChangeDownload <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() { paste('MNCountyPopChangeData', '.csv', sep='') },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(ChangeData, file)
      }) 

    output$cityChangeTable <- renderDataTable({
      data <- CityChange
      if (input$County7 != "All"){
        data <- data[data$County %in% input$County7,]
      }
      data
    }, options =list(aoColumnDefs = list(list(sClass="alignCenter",aTargets=c(list("_all"))  )),  pageLength=10))  

    output$cityChangeChart <- renderChart({
      var <- reactive({input$County8})
      DF <- subset(CityChangeLong, County %in% var())
      names(DF) = gsub("\\.", "", names(DF))
      n4 <- nPlot(PercentChange ~ Year, data = DF, group = "Name", type = 'lineChart')
      n4$addParams(dom = 'cityChangeChart')
      n4$yAxis(axisLabel = "Percent Change from Previous Decade", width = 62)      
      n4$xAxis(axisLabel = "Year")
      n4$xAxis(tickValues=c(1900, 1910, 1920, 1930, 1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010))
      #     n3$chart(forceY = c(-100, 100))
      return(n4)
    })

    output$cityChangeDownload <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() { paste('MNCityPopChangeData', '.csv', sep='') },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(CityChange, file)
      })

    output$twpChangeTable <- renderDataTable({
      data <- TwpChange
      if (input$County9 != "All"){
        data <- data[data$County %in% input$County9,]
      }
      data
    }, options =list(aoColumnDefs = list(list(sClass="alignCenter",aTargets=c(list("_all"))  )), pageLength=10))  

    output$twpChangeChart <- renderChart({
      var <- reactive({input$County10})
      DF <- subset(TwpChangeLong, County %in% var())
      names(DF) = gsub("\\.", "", names(DF))
      n5 <- nPlot(PercentChange ~ Year, data = DF, group = "Name", type = 'lineChart')
      n5$addParams(dom = 'twpChangeChart')
      n5$yAxis(axisLabel = "Percent Change from Previous Decade", width = 62)      
      n5$xAxis(axisLabel = "Year")
      n5$xAxis(tickValues=c(1900, 1910, 1920, 1930, 1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010))
      #     n3$chart(forceY = c(-100, 100))
      return(n5)
    })

    output$twpChangeDownload <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() { paste('MNTownshipPopChangeData', '.csv', sep='') },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(TwpChange, file)
      })


    data(movies, package = "ggplot2")
    minx <- min(movies$rating)
    maxx <- max(movies$rating)

      output$trendPlot <- renderPlotly({
        # size of the bins depend on the input 'bins'
        size <- (maxx - minx) / input$bins

        # a simple histogram of movie ratings
        p <- plot_ly(movies, x = rating, autobinx = F, type = "histogram",
                     xbins = list(start = minx, end = maxx, size = size))
        # style the xaxis
        layout(p, xaxis = list(title = "Ratings", range = c(minx, maxx), autorange = F,
                               autotick = F, tick0 = minx, dtick = size))
      })




  }
```

There is a lot of unused code at the moment because I've not completed the ui. Essentially I'm taking code from a previous shiny code to assemble a shinydashboard.

Comment: Try to make a reproducible example that can be run on a machine other than your own. Try to get to the simplest version of the problem you're running into.

Comment: Consider adding [r] and/or [ggplotly] to the tags. This issue was hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post while looking for a solution to the same problem (although I'm using shiny app not using shinydashboard). I'm not sure why this occurred, but the first two icons would dominate the entire plotly output.

I figured the plotly modebar isn't too important in my case and decided to remove it. Using: `plot_ly(....) %>% config(displayModeBar = F)` found in this thread [Removing the Edit Chart link from an R plotly graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33499917/removing-the-edit-chart-link-from-an-r-plotly-graph) eliminated the plotly modebar and the issue altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more generic solution:

```
.plotly .modebar-btn svg {
  height: 1em!important;
  width: 1em!important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am facing the exact same issue.
It is most definitely because of a clash between `$param$width` and the `param$height` parameter from **rCharts** interfering with **plotly**. There is some activity with regard to the issue [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/702)

**Update**
Editing the html manually and replacing all

```
<div class="modebar modebar--hover">
```

with

```
<div class="modebar modebar--hover" style="
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;">
```

is a possible dirty and "hacky" solution.

There has to be cleaner way to do this, but until then this should help.