# How to remove completely top hower bar or partial while using plotly chart in R?

Tags: r, plotly

How can i remove the top hower bar which has download plot, zoom in or out or options on the  plotly chart in R ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SY0X.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to flipperweid's answer, you can use `config(plot, modeBarButtonsToRemove = list("sendDataToCloud"))` to remove individual buttons

Comment: You can see a current list of modeBarButtons here: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/components/modebar/buttons.js

Answer (score 1):

I google a little for you. This should be simple, use this:

```
config(displayModeBar = F)
```

Look here to the Answer of Vance Lopez: [Removing the Edit Chart link from an R plotly graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33499917/removing-the-edit-chart-link-from-an-r-plotly-graph)

> From the documentation, use config:
>
> Plotly object p
>
> p %>% config(showLink = F) You can see .js config options in action
>   here.
>
> Note: the "save and edit plot in cloud" button in the Mode Bar at the
>   top still exists. You can turn off the Mode Bar with
>
> config(displayModeBar = F) There is a request on GitHub to edit
>   specific Mode Bar buttons.